# What is best way to make a calculation with input values from a html form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a product form with 3 inputs

1. Price (fixed number)
2. Quantity (an input with type="text" where the user can enter a number)
3. Optional extra (a checkbox that the user can tick to add a number)

So far I have been using Javascript to get the value of the html elements, and then adding them and outputting the result into a html element.

I need the form to update on the fly, so that a user can enter a number into quantity and tick the box and the result update live. Unfortuantely I have been unbale to find a way to set variables when there is an update in a field, please see the link below of what I have done so far.

http://jsbin.com/tapen/2/watch?html,css,js,output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Jquery its very easy to acess the value of an input field, or to set events to will execute when the field value is changed / updated.

As a pratical example i would suggest that you take a look in the code of a sample calculator using only jquery and html: http://firstemission.blogspot.com.br/2012/10/jquery-and-watermark-example.html